# Scatter plot of two different data frames r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm very new to R and searched quite a bit but couldn't find an answer to this question.

I have two data frames that are formatted exactly the same way, where rows equal countries and columns equal years. I want to create a scatter plot where data frame 1 is X and data frame 2 is Y.

For example:

```
 Data frame 1:

        1991  1992
 USA       1     3
 Canada    4     5


 Data frame 2:

        1991  1992
 USA     200   129
 Canada  245   342
```

Any suggestion for how I should being?

Comment: What do you mean by "data frame 1 is X and data frame 2 is Y", `x=c(1,4,3,5)` vs `y=c(200,245,129,342)`?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm guessing right, this is probably what you looking for. Just add a geom_point() layer plotting data from a second dataframe:

```
#Create dataframe A
a.country <- rep(c("USA", "Canada"), 2)
a.value   <- as.numeric(c(1, 4, 3, 5))
a.year    <- c("1991", "1991", "1992", "1992")
dtframe.a <- data.frame(a.country, a.year, a.value)

#Create dataframe B
b.country <- rep(c("USA", "Canada"), 2)
b.value   <- c(200, 245, 129, 342)
b.year    <- c("1991", "1991", "1992", "1992")
dtframe.b <- data.frame(b.country, b.year, b.value)

# Use ggplot2 to plot data from 2 dataframes
require(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=dtframe.a, aes(a.year, a.value, color= a.country)) +
  geom_point(data=dtframe.b, aes(b.year, b.value, color= b.country))
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the scatter plot commands I know use different columns in the same data frame.  I would suggest merging your two dataframes into one.  It's not clear whether you want to plot the 1991 and 1992 values together or separately, so I'm following DanielRP and assuming you will plot them together (but in a scatterplot).  You could make year a condition in the plotting to plot them separately. Here is an example that will hopefully get you started:

```
#Create dataframe 1
country <- rep(c("USA", "Canada"), 2)
x.value   <- as.numeric(c(1, 4, 3, 5))
year    <- c("1991", "1991", "1992", "1992")
df.1 <- data.frame(country, year, x.value)

#Create dataframe 2
country <- rep(c("USA", "Canada"), 2)
y.value   <- c(200, 245, 129, 342)
year    <- c("1991", "1991", "1992", "1992")
df.2 <- data.frame(country, year, y.value)

#Merge the two dataframes based on 'country' (since this is identical in both)
new.df<-merge(df.1,df.2)

#Make your scatterplot
plot(new.df$x.value,new.df$y.value,xlab="X value",ylab="Y value")
```

That's a very simple plot, so depending on your needs you might prefer to use ggplot2 or another package.

Comment: In fact, merging is not needed here. plot(df.1$x.value,df.2$y.value,xlab="X value",ylab="Y value") works just as well, as you are passing two numeric vectors to the plot function. ggplot requires the same dataframe, though.